# spring boot swagger springfox generates invalid spec for oauth/token endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I want to add token endpoint oauth/token into my API documentation so I configured Docket like this:

```
public Docket api(UserProperties userProperties) {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error")))
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/oauth/authorize")))
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/oauth/check_token")))
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/oauth/token_key")))
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/oauth/confirm_access")))
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/oauth/error")))
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }
```

swagger-ui display page correctly, however 3rd party validator claims that:

```
Swagger schema validation failed.
 Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf' at #/paths//oauth/token/post/parameters/1
   Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf' at #/paths//oauth/token/post/parameters/1
     Missing required property: schema at #/
     Missing required property: type at #/
   Missing required property: $ref at #/paths//oauth/token/post/parameters/1

JSON_OBJECT_VALIDATION_FAILED
```

The swagger.json taken from /api/v2/api-docs:

```
"/oauth/token": {
          "get": {
            ...
          },
          "post": {
            "tags": [
              "token-endpoint"
            ],
            "summary": "postAccessToken",
            "operationId": "postAccessTokenUsingPOST",
            "consumes": [
              "application/json"
            ],
            "produces": [
              "*/*"
            ],
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "name",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "name": "parameters",
                "in": "query",
                "description": "parameters",
                "required": true,
                "items": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "additionalProperties": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "responses": {
              ...
            },
            "deprecated": false
          }
        },
```

Why springfox generates invalid schema?